# Google Map interfering with button event in Safari

Tags: forms, google-maps, submit, safari

If you press "Upload your file" in the test code below, the button text should change to "Uploading...", although in Safari it doesn't. Selecting a sufficiently large file should just give you time to observe the button. Comment out map div and it all works fine.

Here's the isolated test code, it took half a day to find that the map could be the cause, but I need to dig deeper. Interestingly, when copying the same code to JSfiddle it will not reproduce the bug, so you'll need to create your own html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Map interfering with button event in Safari</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function init() {
  var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!--comment map to see correct button behaviour in Safari-->
    <div id="map" style="width:300px;height:300px"></div>

    <p><small>Very large file please:</small> <input type="file" name="big"></p>
    <button onclick="this.innerHTML='Uploading...'">Upload your file</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

There were similar questions on SO before, but no solutions.

Comment: Anyone managed to reproduce the buggy button behaviour in Safari?

Comment: Filed an issue on GMaps API Issues here http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4443. Feel free to star it if you are experiencing similar difficulties.